Are Bitbucket branches pipelines running before or after the commit to that branch?
I am adding a production deployment pipeline to a Bitbucket project. The YAML file is roughly
image: php:8.2.20

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: Deploying to production
          deployment: production
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-client
            - ssh $PROD_SSH_USER@$PROD_SSH_HOST "bash -s" < scripts/production.sh

(Note: the YAML file only shows the essential part, the image is required for other tasks.)
The production.sh scripts is basically:
#!/bin/bash

cd /path/to/project

git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master

# further installation steps

However, the git reset does not fetch the latest commit. Is it because the pipeline runs before the commit to the master branch is done?
If not, why isn't git reset pulling the latest commit?
If so, how can I get the commit being set to master?

@SyedM.Sannan you want my question to be downvoted and closed before anyone can answer? If some admin could move this question to devops, then I agree that it should go there.

The commit happens on the machine where the change was made, these changes are then pushed to the remote repository through git push origin HEAD or similar. So the commit has happened by the time your deployment pipeline runs.
I think perhaps you are duplicating some work, you haven't posted the full YAML so I can't tell for sure, but the pipeline should be configured to clone the repository
Workflow to access an arbitrary branch in same git
Assuming BitBucket has been configured to checkout a copy of the repository and execute commands in the repository as it's "working directory" then you could safely use:
git checkout origin/master
This will put the repository into a Detached Head state, and give you access to the head commit on origin/master and then execute your code from there.
Workflow to access a different git repo
If you need a different repo you can access this through:
git clone [repo-uri]
git checkout master

master is probably the default branch, so the second command is probably unnecessary but I don't know your config for sure.
General Troubleshooting
It can be helpful to add some troubleshooting commands to the pipeline in times like this:

echo $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR - will print the clone directory
pwd - will print the current working directory
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all will give you some idea of the state of the tree

I'd also suggest checking out the repository in a different directory/folder on a local machine, and checking everything is where it's supposed to be. Sometimes, someone pushes some changes which look okay, but in practice are wrong:

check the mainline branch is master not main
check the origin/master branch ref got updated to the latest commit, sometimes a botched command locally can result in pushing commits but not updating the ref
check the commit exists at all

